# How to convert a string of nested array to array without quotes in javascript without the use of eval, string can be also in a form of latex

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, latex, jsxgraph

How to convert a string of nested array to an array without quotes in javascript. I want to do without using `eval()`

```
"[[[a,f],[b]],[[c]],[d],[e]]" into [[["a","f"],["b"]],[["c"]],["d"],["e"]]

d  = eval("[[[a,f],[b]],[[c]],[d],[e]]".replace(/(\w+)/g, '"$1"'))
```

Gives the solution, but I don't want to use eval
It can also be in latex
"[[\\frac{a}{b}]]" for this JSON.parse won't work

Comment: Build a tiny parser?

Comment: What is `[[[a,f],[b]],[[c]],[d],[e]]`? What are the `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, and `f` there?

Comment: The whole ``` [[[a,f],[b]],[[c]],[d],[e]] is string```

Comment: @MayankSharma "Not working" isn't helpful. It'd be pretty straight-forward, although Nina's approach is a lot easier. OTOH, good exercise.

Comment: "[[\\frac{3232}{334}]]" try this

Answer (score 6):

You could treat the new string as a JSON and parse it.

```js
let d = JSON.parse("[[[a,f],[b]],[[c]],[d],[e]]".replace(/(\w+)/g, '"$1"'));

console.log(d);
```

Comment: var d = "[[\\frac{3232}{334}]]" failing for this

Comment: what is it? it looks different of the question.

Comment: This is written in latex, I am trying to parse an answer type which can be in latex() or without latex, I am using mathquill

Comment: and what is the javascript equivalent?

Comment: mathquill itself written in javascript